# Updating jQuery from 1.8 to 1.11 <a> tag not getting appended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update this javascript code from `1.8` to `1.11`, and I am having issues. The following code used to work in `1.8`, but now it only half works (without errors).

I have the following function:

```
function selectCountry(c_id){
    var obj = $('#country a[data-index=' + c_id + ']');
    if(obj.hasClass('cselect'))
        return;
    var clone = obj.clone();
    var div = $('<div class="keyword-box"></div>');
    var remove = $('<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-index="' + c_id + '" data-label="removeCountry_label" data-action="removeCountry" class="remove EXremove">&times;</a>');
    clone.after(remove).appendTo(div);
    div.prependTo('#selected_country');
    obj.hide().addClass('cselect');
    return false;
}
```

What it used to do is create a div like this:

```
<div class="keyword-box">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="country-link keyword" data-index="9" rel="Albania">Albania</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-index="9" data-label="removeCountry_label" data-action="removeCountry" class="remove EXremove">×</a>
</div>
```

But now it is creating a div like this:

```
<div class="keyword-box">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="country-link keyword" data-index="9" rel="Albania">Albania</a>
</div>
```

I am not sure why the second `a` tag isn't getting added to the div any more. Can anyone see why this is happening?

Comment: Any error? Were you using `.live`?

Comment: No errors, and I was using live, but I removed all of them and replaced it with `on`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's been a [change in jQuery](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#after-before-and-replacewith-with-disconnected-nodes) at version 1.9

> Prior to 1.9, .after(), .before(), and .replaceWith() would attempt to
>   add or change nodes in the current jQuery set if the first node in the
>   set was not connected to a document, and in those cases return a new
>   jQuery set rather than the original set. This created several
>   inconsistencies and outright bugs--the method might or might not
>   return a new result depending on its arguments! As of 1.9, these
>   methods always return the original unmodified set and attempting to
>   use .after(), .before(), or .replaceWith() on a node without a parent
>   has no effect--that is, neither the set or the nodes it contains are
>   changed.

In your case you can just change

```
clone.after(remove).appendTo(div);
```

to

```
clone.add(remove).appendTo(div);
```

or

```
div.append(clone, remove);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your code would be much more readable if you would add the links like this:

```
div.append(clone);
div.append(remove);
div.prependTo('#selected_country');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.after()` API changed in jQuery 1.9. Using it in your case now has no effect. I think you should probably create the `<div>` and explicitly append both `<a>` elements individually to it.

So:

```
var div = $('<div class="keyword-box"></div>');
var remove = $('<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-index="' + c_id + '" data-label="removeCountry_label" data-action="removeCountry" class="remove EXremove">&times;</a>');

remove.appendTo(div);
clone.appendTo(div);
```